# dart_frog | How do I define multiple routes in same file?

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-frog

Below is my current routes:

- `api/v1/users/login`
- `api/v1/users/register`
- `api/v1/users/forgot`

And so on...

I want to know, how can I create all these routes keeping a single file `auth.dart` let's say. So that I will be having all the code in single file related to authentications but the routes will remain as they are above mentioned.

Here's the current folder structure that is creating routes:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dart Frog does not support having multiple routes in a single file, as it is a file-based routing framework.

What you can do however is setup the routes as you have in the screenshot, and define both a middleware and inject an `AuthManager`:

```dart
// In your _middleware.dart
final _authManager = AuthManager();

Handler middleware(Handler handler) {
  return handler
      .use(provider<AuthManager>((_) => _authManager));
}

// In any of your routes
FutureOr<Response> onRequest(RequestContext context, String id) async {
  final authManager = context.read<AuthManager>();

  // Do something with authManager
}
```

If you want your `AuthManager` to be per request, instead of using a global value you can construct it every time the `create`, that is the method you pass to the provider, is called:

```dart
// In your _middleware.dart

Handler middleware(Handler handler) {
  return handler.use(
    provider<AuthManager>((context) {
      // Do something with context

      return AuthManager(...);
    }),
  );

}
```

See [the docs about dependency injection](https://dartfrog.vgv.dev/docs/basics/dependency-injection) for more information